# Enabling Wi-Fi on HP 15-r208nk

Tags: 14.04, wireless, realtek

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop, a HP 15-r208nk, and I don't know how to enable my laptop's WiFi connection.

Output of `lsusb` and `lspci -v`:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05c8:036e Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:b001 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView SSA-CUnit (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2213
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView Gen7 (rev 0e) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2213
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 107
    Memory at 90000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at 80000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3050 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView 6-Port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0e) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2213
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 105
    I/O ports at 3048 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 305c [size=4]
    I/O ports at 3040 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 3058 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 3020 [size=32]
    Memory at 90a1f000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 0e) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2213
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 103
    Memory at 90a00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView SEC (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2213
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at 90900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at 90800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation ValleyView High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2213
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 108
    Memory at 90a10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: fast devsel
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: 90700000-907fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff
    Memory behind bridge: 90600000-906fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
    Memory behind bridge: 90500000-905fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000090400000-00000000904fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView USB Enhanced Host Controller (rev 0e) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2213
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at 90a18000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2213
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation ValleyView SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2213
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 7
    Memory at 90a19000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2231
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at 90700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2213
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 104
    Memory at 90600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci

04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2213
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 106
    I/O ports at 1000 [size=256]
    Memory at 90500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 90400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

How do I fix Wi-Fi on my laptop?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the results from `rfkill list all`

Comment: amine@amineHTB:~$ rfkill list all
1: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: this is what i got

Answer (score 0):

This should make your wifi work

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/ker...9-rc1-1.tar.xz
tar -xf backports-3.19-rc1-1.tar.xz
cd ~/backports-3.19-rc1-1
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot